# React native , open a url in webview

Tags: react-native

Im not familiar  with ios app development , but is there a simple way to open a url in myApp's webview , in a simple way ?

Im looking for the same behaviour of facebook's app. once you click on http link , a webview is opened by the app.

```
clickHndlr: function() {
   someNativeOrNonNativeModule.openUrl('http://google.com');
}


<Text onClick={this.clickHndlr}>google</Text>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can use WebView component in reactnative.

```
var {
  ....,
  WebView,
} = React;
```

and in initial state give a default url or no url

```
getInitialState: function() {
 return {
  url: '', // or default url
  yourInitialStates: 'value',
 };
},
```

and then at inside render add component

```
<WebView ....your styles, properties
  url={this.state.url}
/>
```

Now add your code

```
clickHndlr: function() {
 this.setState({url:'http://google.com'});
}
```

This will give the result

Comment: This probably works . i thought there is a an api for that . calling to a native api , will cause the same behaviour

Comment: sorry, no native apis for that. If you found answer useful check the tick.